# Local Cohen-Macaulay rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings, cohen-macaulay

**Case one:**

Let $(R,m)$ be a Noetherian local ring of Krull dimension $d$, $\dim(R)=d$.

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.

Assume that $\operatorname{depth}(I,R)=d$, namely, the maximal length of a regular sequence in $I$ is $d$.

**Claim:** $R$ is [Cohen-Macaulay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Macaulay_ring).

**Proof of claim:** We need to show that $\operatorname{depth}(m,R)=\dim(R)$.

Let $\{x_1,\ldots,x_d\} \subset I \subseteq m$, where $\{x_1,\ldots,x_d\}$ is a [regular sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_sequence) (in $I$); then it is also a regular sequence in $m$.
Therefore, $m$ contains a regular sequence of length $d$,
so by definition, $\operatorname{depth}(m,R) \geq d$.

It is known that $\operatorname{depth}(m,R) \leq \dim(R)=d$, so we have
$d \leq \operatorname{depth}(m,R) \leq \dim(R)=d$,
which shows that $\operatorname{depth}(m,R) = \dim(R)$.

> **Question 1:** Are my above claim and proof correct?

It seems to me a very easy result; my reason for asking it is to validate that I have not missed something, especially if I applied the definitions correctly.

---

**Edit:**

**Case 2:**

Let $(R,m)$ be a Noetherian local ring of finite Krull dimension $d$, $\dim(R)=d$.

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.

**Claim:** $\operatorname{depth}(I,R) \leq d$.

**Proof of claim:** It is easy to see directly from the definition of depth and the fact that $I \subseteq m$ that
$\operatorname{depth}(I,R) \leq \operatorname{depth}(m,R)$.

It is known that $\operatorname{depth}(m,R) \leq \dim(R)=d$, so we have
$\operatorname{depth}(I,R) \leq \operatorname{depth}(m,R) \leq \dim(R)=d$.

**Question 2:** Are my above claim and proof correct?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think everything's fine.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier, thank you for your comment; glad to hear. Maybe I will add to the above question an additional relevant question.